# StreamWriter не записывает данные в .txt

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

пытаюсь запаковать поток в архив, который собственно в памяти

```
public static byte[] sWrite(List<Play> Player)
{

}
//
List<Play> player = Online.Get(server);
//


using var mem = new MemoryStream { Position = 0 };
{
    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(mem)
    streamWriter.Write(cSer.sWrite(player)); //cSer - class 
    streamWriter.Flush();
    mem.ToArray();
}
```

с помощью

```
storer.AddStream(ZipStorer.Compression.Deflate, $"{bSavePath}" + $"\\text_{name}({GenStrings.GenNumbersTo()}).txt", mem, DateTime.Now, null);
```

только вот текстовый файл в архиве пустой =(

но когда использую

```
var mem = new MemoryStream(cSer.sWrite(player).ToArray());
```

создаётся текстовый файл в архиве, с данными в ней. мне обязательно надо использовать первый вариант с `StreamWriter`, как быть?

Comment: что возвращает `cSer.sWrite(player)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После записи в поток с помощью `mem.Write`, надо позицию возвращать на начало перед последующим чтением.

```cs
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    byte[] data = cSer.sWrite(player);
    mem.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    mem.Position = 0;
    storer.AddStream(...);
}
```

С `.ToArray()` работает, потому что позиция не влияет на этот метод.

Кстати, непонятно, зачем вам `StreamWriter`. Если надо записать в архив массив байт как поток, то вот этот код выглядит совершенно нормально:

```cs
var mem = new MemoryStream(cSer.sWrite(player));
```

Comment: сделал как вы сказали, просто сбрасываю позицию для последующей записи

Comment: @AleksandrPistoletov вам не нужен StreamWriter, он вообще для записи текстов, вы можете напрямую `mem.Write` использовать в таком случае, и `mem.ToArray()` тоже не нужен, это просто лишний, никак не используемый вызов. Я дополнил код в ответе.

Comment: Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'offset' of 'MemoryStream.Write(byte[], int, int)'

Comment: @AleksandrPistoletov это легко объехать, поправил код. Вероятно, вы используете старый .NET Framework, а там нет перегрузки метода записи для `Span<T>`, поэтому можно по-старинке, что я и сделал в доработанном коде.

Comment: @AleksandrPistoletov либо если я ошибаюсь с версией фреймворка, то еще так можно попробовать `mem.Write(cSer.sWrite(player).AsSpan());` но по идее ошибка, которую вы показали, не должна была возникнуть. Какая версия дотнета и тип приложения у вас?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.5, тип - консольный. меня все устраивает, благодарю

Comment: @AleksandrPistoletov поменяйте хотя-бы целевой фреймворк на 4.7.2, у 4.5.2 все плохо с сетью, он сильно устарел. Вы же наверняка настраиваете TLS для ServicePoint, чтобы оно заработало, так вот начиная с 4.6.1 оно работает без настроек. Поменял код в ответе на старый C#.

Comment: хотел задать вопрос вам, но в комментариях символы ограничены https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315722/%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0